# closed subscheme of ind scheme

Tags: schemes, ind-schemes, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ a ind-scheme of ind-finite type and ind-affine. (e.g, take a k- smooth, affine scheme of finte type $T$, $C$ a smooth projective curve over $k$ and $x$ a closed point, then $X=T(C-x)$ verifies all the properties

Let $Y\subset X$ a closed subscheme of $X$, do we know if $Y$ is locally of finite type?

Comment: maybe we also need to assume that $X$ is a indscheme over a countable set.

Comment: By `$T(C-x)$` do you mean `$\text{Hom}(C-x,T)$` ?

Comment: yes,  that's right.

Comment: SGA3 uses the notation $\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}_k(C-x,T)$ to indicate the Hom sheaf.  The underline is to keep people from mistaking it for the Hom-set.
